# Powershell seems to store multiple presses of the enter key

Tags: powershell

I was working on a PowerShell script to add users to Active Directory from a csv file by generating usernames from their first and last names. After making an initial username (first initial + last name), it checks if this username already exists. If it does, it asks for confirmation to try first initial + middle initial + last name. Currently, I do this with the following code:

```
write-host "Default username is already taken. Please press enter tocontinue or type NO to skip importing this user.
$PROMPT = Read-Host '>'
$PROMPT = $PROMPT.ToLower()

#If not skipped, continue with logic
if ($PROMPT -ne "no")
{
    ...
}
```

This seems to work, but if I accidentially press enter two times, for example, it not only confirms the current prompt but the next one as well. I'm pretty new to PowerShell, so I'm guessing there's a better way to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You could pop up some sort of message box. There are a few different ways to do that. Here's one easy way:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$msg = "Default username is already taken. Continue?"
$r = $wshell.Popup($msg, 0, "Warning", 4)
if ($r -eq 6)
{
    # Continue ...
}
```

For an explanation of the mysterious numbers 4 and 6, see [Popup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your script such that the input should be y/yes or n/no. If it's not either of those, prompt again.

This would eliminate accidentally confirming a change, but would require that you specifically press a key then enter to confirm or skip.

Possibly better ways to do this, but that's my initial thought.

As an aside, you can skip the `$PROMPT = $PROMPT.ToLower()` line. `-eq` isn't case sensitive, so the following works:

```
PS C:\> 'NO' -eq 'no'
True
```

If you want string comparison to be case sensitive, look for the operators that start with a c, like `-ceq`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! I figured I could do something like this, just wondered why it was saving multiple inputs - I feel like it will probably do the same thing if I typed "y" multiple times, though that's harder to do accidentially

Comment: @Krixvar, `Read-Host` takes everything you type up until you press enter, so if you pressed y twice, you'd just end up with a string of 'yy' waiting for you to press enter (and fail if you do hit enter because it isn't a valid response.)

As to why... I don't know. I don't even know if it is unique to PowerShell. You can see this all over the place by running a long running command, hitting enter a few times while it runs, and then when it's finished you'll see a bunch of prompts pop up underneath as it processes those key presses.